# AJAX: Return from PHP fires error: requested JSON parse failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I run my little javascript with an AJAX call to PHP it always returns with a JSON parsererror.

In PHP I can see that my json is filled with an array like this:
json encode: `{"Year":"2012","Make":"Ford","Model":"Taurus","Error":"no error"}`

[This](http://mycarbio.livedemo.click/test-form/) is the site:

The AJAX will be called when the visitor leaves the field VIN on the left and should fill the 3 fields on the right automatically.

```js
function decode_my_vin(myvin) {

alert("javascript began");

dataoneID  = '00000';
dataoneKEY = 'x0x0x';

jQuery.ajax(
    {
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/vin-decoder.php',
 dataType: "json",
    data: { 
   'value1_VIN': myvin,
   'value2_ID': dataoneID,
   'value3_KEY': dataoneKEY,
  },
 success: function(response) {
  
   var resultYear = response.Year;
   var resultMake = response.Make;
   var resultModel = response.Model;
   var resultMessage = response.Message;
   alert("success returned: Year " + resultYear + " Make " + resultMake + " Model " + resultModel + " Message " + resultMessage); 

      document.getElementById("fld_7290902_1").value = resultYear;
      document.getElementById("fld_1595243_1").value = resultMake;
      document.getElementById("fld_7532728_1").value = resultModel;
      document.getElementById("fld_7532728_1").value = resultMessage;

   return;
  },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
  alert("Error in jquery: " + msg); 
        $('#post').html(msg);
 },
 complete: function(value) {
   alert("returned after complete: " + value);
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $vinResult = array(
      'Year'  => '2012',
      'Make'  => 'Ford',
      'Model' => 'Taurus',
      'Error' => 'No Error'
 );

    echo json_encode($vinResult);
?>
```

Comment: Put your script in `document.ready` function and link your JS file after jQuery. Because, when I inspect your site I found error `$` not defined and no ajax request was sent.

Comment: Hmm.. nice but what's your question?

Comment: @Novice: The question is: WHY would the correct json which was build in php not show up in the success part of my calling AJAX and why does it fire the error part with a json parsererror instead. And last but not least: what can I do to fix this problem.

Comment: @HarishKommuri:I'm not sure whether I understand you. My php writes a debuglog and this log shows the PHP runs each time when I leave the entry field VIN and it builds the json string correctly before it terminates. Then I get the parsererror in my JS

Answer (score 0):

In your error function of ajax call, it gives error for `$('#post').html(msg);` saying not function. Try using `jQuery('#post')` instead of `$('#post')`.

To parse your response, use `var data = jQuery.parseJSON( response );` and then access fields by `data.Year` etc.